# SQLite update sets column's value instead of given value. How to fix it?

Tags: angular, sqlite

I'm trying to update some values in a sqlite table. In the update query if some of the fields has the name of a table's column, the value ends up as the value of that column instead of the given value.

I tried looking for an answer on other question but didn't find any. I don't know if I'm mising a concept here or there is a sqlite limitation.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    barcode TEXT,
    sku TEXT
)
```

Lets say I add an example product with the following query:

`INSERT INTO product (id, name, barcode, sku) VALUES (1, "Product Example", "2095063206626", "SKU912132151")`

Whenever I try to update it with a query that includes a value that references a column name, for example:

`UPDATE product SET name = "Product edited", barcode = "ID", sku = "BARCODE" WHERE id = 1`

It sets the value as the column's current value for the given row, and I end up with this object on the database:

```
{
    "id" = 1
    "name" = "Product edited"
    "barcode" = 1
    "sku" = "2095063206626"
}
```

And I'm actually expecting this:

```
{
    "id" = 1
    "name" = "Product edited"
    "barcode" = "ID"
    "sku" = "BARCODE"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In SQL, double quotes are for *identifiers*, like the column named ID. Single quotes are for strings. You're setting `barcode` to the value of the `ID` column.

Comment: @Shawn Since I was using angular, I used single quotes to identify the query string and double quotes for the string fields of the query. I will try changing for single quotes and see if it fixes it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by using double quotes for strings in the query. Double quotes are used for identifiers in sqlite, as pointed out by @Shawn.